# Prove the inequality $1\le\int_1^4 \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I want to prove the inequality:

$$1\le\int_1^4 \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}} \,dx$$

This is my attempt:

The domain is $(0,\infty)$ and the range is $[0,1]$

So, $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}} \ge \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{9}}=\frac{1}{4}$ (used a value for x=9)

So, $1\ge\int_1^4 \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}} \,dx \ge \int_1^4 \frac{1}{4} \,dx = \frac{3}{4}$, but this is not a proof. I don't think this is the way I should calculate this inequality

Can anyone help me where I got it wrong? Am I on the right track? Or am I way wrong?

Many thanks:)

Comment: Formatting note:  `\sqrt{x}` or `\sqrt x` produces $\sqrt x$ and looks better than `\sqrt(x)`, which produces $\sqrt(x)$

Comment: When you see a satisfactory answer you should accept it by hitting the check mark under the upvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $x\leq 4$, we have that

$$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}}\geq \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{4}}=\frac{1}{1+2}=\frac{1}{3}$$

and so

$$\int_{1}^4\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}}dx\geq \int_{1}^4\frac{1}{3}dx=1$$

Comment: Exactly how i did it, nice :)

Comment: Thank you!!!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is correct but you picked $x=9$ instead of $x=4$. We have for $x\in [1,4]$

$$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}}\geq \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{4}}=\frac{1}{1+2}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Then

$$\int_1^4 \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}}dx\geq \int_1^4 \frac{1}{3}dx =\frac{3}{3}=1$$

Comment: Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the integral **unwillingly** by trying a change of variable to make the expression more friendly. With $x=t^2$,

$$\int_1^4\frac{dx}{1+\sqrt x}=\int_1^2\frac{2t\,dt}{1+t}=2-2\int_1^2\frac{dt}{1+t}=2-2\log\frac32>1.$$

---

Anyway, without integrating, the new integrand is upward convex and stays above the line segment $(1,1)$ to $\left(2,\dfrac43\right)$, and the area of the trapezium is $\dfrac76>1$.